# LeetCode problem: 2623. Memorize showing wrong answer for testcase 18/20

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [2623. Memoize](https://leetcode.com/problems/memoize/description/):

> Given a function `fn`, return a memoized version of that function.
>
> A memoized function is a function that will never be called twice with the same inputs. Instead it will return a cached value.
>
> You can assume there are 3 possible input functions: `sum`, `fib`, and `factorial`.
>
> - `sum` accepts two integers `a` and `b` and returns `a + b`.
> - `fib` accepts a single integer `n` and returns 1 if `n <= 1` or `fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)` otherwise.
> - `factorial` accepts a single integer `n` and returns 1 if `n <= 1` or `factorial(n - 1) * n` otherwise.

Below is my code in JavaScript for the problem, but in LeetCode it is showing wrong answer for a test case. The code in comment blocks is provided by LeetCode:

```
/**
 * @param {Function} fn
 * @return {Function}
 */
function memoize(fn) {
    let arr = [];
    let result = [];
    return function (...args) {
        if (!(arr.toString().match(args.toString()))) {
            arr.push(args);
            let val = fn(...args);
            result.push(val);
            return val;
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i].toString() === args.toString()) {
                    return result[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


/** 
 * let callCount = 0;
 * const memoizedFn = memoize(function (a, b) {
 *   callCount += 1;
 *   return a + b;
 * })
 * memoizedFn(2, 3) // 5
 * memoizedFn(2, 3) // 5
 * console.log(callCount) // 1 
 */
```

Failing test case:

```
let callCount = 0;
const memoizedFn = memoize(function (a, b) {
   callCount += 1;
   return a + b;
})
memoizedFn(122, 931)
memoizedFn(34, 216)
memoizedFn(22, 9)
memoizedFn(1, 803)
callCount // Expected 4, my code has 3
```

Even though for other "sum" input test cases results were accepted, but for the input mentioned here, I get the wrong answer.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your question must not depend on any 3rd party site. You cannot assume familiarity with the problem (=> explain what is the function supposed to do), then provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ideally using a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers). Then you should also provide the input where it fails and what exactly prevents you from debugging/ correcting that case.

Comment: I replaced your unreadable test case with a much smaller one, in JavaScript notation. Have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you hope to find the arguments in the array `arr` by doing:

```
arr.toString().match(args.toString())
```

It has to be said that if you want to test for a substring presence, `includes` would be the method. `match` actually turns its argument into a regular expression, which is not appropriate here.

But more importantly, this substring test will return false positives. Let's say the function was already called with arguments 11 and 12 (to perform `sum(11, 12)`) and then it is called with arguments 1 and 1 (to perform `sum(1, 1)`), then the above expression really is:

```
"11,12".match("1,1")
```

...and that will return a truthy value. You can see your code fail with this test case:

```js
function memoize(fn) {
    let arr = [];
    let result = [];
    return function (...args) {
        if (!(arr.toString().match(args.toString()))) {
            arr.push(args);
            let val = fn(...args);
            result.push(val);
            return val;
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i].toString() === args.toString()) {
                    return result[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Using the sum function as example for memoization
let callCount = 0;
function sum(a, b) {
    callCount += 1;
    return a + b;
}

const memoSum = memoize(sum);
memoSum(11, 12);
memoSum(1, 1);
console.log(callCount); // Outputs 1, but it should output 2
```

Also, it is not very efficient to have to perform a `for` loop to actually find the result for a previously memoized set of arguments.

What you really want to use here is a fast lookup table, like with a plain object, or with a `Map`. The key to use with such structure could be `args.toString()`, but you'll have a more robust solution if you stringify the arguments with `JSON.stringify`.

So a correction could be:

```
function memoize(fn) {
    const cache = {};
    return function(...args) {
        return cache[JSON.stringify(args)] ??= fn(...args);
    }
}
```